# Sum across multiple associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm trying to tally up the total responses across multiple questions, but it's a bit more complex than that.

I have `Notifications` that belong to `Questions` And then `Responses` that belong to `Questions`.

Notifications are the start of the chain. For example, I'd have 2 `notification` records:

```
[
   #<Notification id: 1, question_id: 58, email: "bob@example.com", frequency: "daily">,
   #<Notification id: 2, question_id: 25, email: "bob@example.com", frequency: "daily"`>
]
```

What I want to find is the total number of `responses` for those notifications. Again, `notifications` and `responses` belong to `questions`.

It'd basically be the same as adding up `notification.question.responses.count` for each of those. Just trying to figure out a more direct way of going about that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked what the generated SQL is for `notification.question.responses.count`? ActiveRecord should come up with the right query for that.

If your concern is making this call for every notification in the list and you want to get the count when you first pull down the list of notifications, put a counter_cache on the Response belongs to question association. Then you can `:include => [:question]` when you request the list of notifications.

Comment: That would work for each individual notification...I'm asking for doing a count for multiple notifications. As if I looped over both the notifications in my example and got the total count for both.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you(Not Tested)

```
Notification.joins("JOIN responses ON responses.question_id = notifications.question_id").group(:question_id).count
```